# All conditional data required in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three table `a`,`b`,`c` having  `id` common between them.

```
Table a:-
id      name      value
 1        a         4
 2        v          6

Table b:-
id      abc
 2        54
 3        56

Table c:-
id       bcd
1         54
3         34
```

Now what i want is what ever is id in where condition, data comes from all tables.

Please advice me how to do that.

Expected Result-

if query is

```
select * from a left join b on a.id=b.id left join c on a.id=c.id where b.id=3

id  name   value   bcd   abc
3    NULL  NULL    34    56
```

if query is

```
select * from a left join b on a.id=b.id left join c on a.id=c.id where a.id=1

id  name   value   bcd   abc
3    a      4       54    NULL
```

Comment: Please post some of the sql that didn't work as it will help with understanding your tables.

Comment: You say that joins fail here. I say that you fail at making joins. Please post your current (wrong) attempt at the query.

Comment: @AjayKadyan - What's your expected output for the given sample data?

Comment: @hims056 if id is available on single table in that condition data also comes having null or zero value of other tables coloum.

Comment: Since there are several choices on how to return the data, please post the expected result of your example. This is not a fortune-teller club and we aren't going to guess what you have in mind.

Comment: Proof that your returned result is wrong (the last query in the question) (note the incorrect id): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d5c/1

Comment: change a.id=3 or c.id = 3 in where condition http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d5c/2

Comment: ... Couldn't this be solved by introducing `WHERE (a.id = 1 OR b.id = 1 OR c.id = 1)` as a filter?

Comment: @Josien i can't do that. actually these tables have more than 10 crore records each and this condtion takes lots of time

Comment: But your query states a.id = 1. How is it possible it returns 3 as id...?

Comment: Then I would create a new "join" table that includes all possible ID's, and join all your tables to this one. You can then always filter on the ID of the safe "join" table.

Comment: @AndriusNaruševičius where condition depends upon user selection process. That's why i am looking out for a common query working on all condition.

Comment: @Josien its not possible. If I can do that I had already done that. :)

Comment: Darn... So much for all my good suggestions :-) This sounds like an interesting challenge, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this approach to the problem? :)

```
SELECT 
    z.id,
    a.name,
    a.value,
    c.bcd,
    b.abc
FROM 
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT y.id id
        FROM
            (
                SELECT id FROM a
                    UNION ALL
                SELECT id FROM b
                    UNION ALL
                SELECT id FROM c
            ) y     
    ) z
    LEFT JOIN a ON z.id = a.id
    LEFT JOIN b ON z.id = b.id
    LEFT JOIN c ON z.id = c.id
where z.id = 3
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d5c/18)

This way you just need to give the query the number not caring about which tables it exists in.

Comment: thanks.you are right we can approach this way. I solved this issue by this approach before posting your ans. but you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's depends on what you are setting in `WHERE` condition. If you are setting `WHERE b.ID = 3` then you need to join other tables with B like this:

```
SELECT A.ID AS A_ID,A.Name, A.value
      ,B.Id as B_ID,B.abc
      ,C.id AS C_ID, c.bcd 
  FROM b 
  LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = b.id 
  LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id 
 WHERE b.id=3;
```

This is happens because `b.ID = 3` is not in Table A and Table C is joined with Table A.
If you set Table A.ID = 1 then you have to join other tables with A using `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT A.ID AS A_ID,A.Name, A.value
      ,B.Id as B_ID,B.abc
      ,C.id AS C_ID, c.bcd 
  FROM A 
  LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = b.id 
  LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id 
 WHERE A.id=1;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43fb6/9)

Answer (score 0):

This is technically impossible, when you are using ID in where how can you get data in case there Id not present in any of the perticular table, you are changing the logic of where ;).

But what you can do is

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT AID AS ID,NAME,VALUE FROM A
UNION
SELECT BID as ID,NAME,NULL AS VALUE FROM B
UNION
SELECT CID as ID,NAME ,NULL AS VALUE FROM C)
WHERE ID =''

Hope this helps

else please clarify. what you want.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Answer (score 0):

I will try to guess, even though I barely find an explanation to the expected result:

```
SELECT 
    b.id,
    a.name,
    a.value,
    c.bcd,
    b.abc
FROM 
    b
    INNER JOIN c ON b.id = c.id
    LEFT JOIN a ON b.id = a.id
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d5c/3)